# Does JDBC (in Spring Data JPA) does not always take JVM default time zone while inserting a record into Oracle DB?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, timezone

At the start of my application,I have set default timezone as Australia/Perth using `Timezone.setDefaultTimezone()` method in java. I am trying to insert a time stamp with Australia timezone in `created_date` column. When the `save` method of Spring data JPA is called, the time stamp is 4 pm Australia time zone. But, inside DB , it is stored as 4 pm UTC. Our Spring config does not force JDBC to use UTC timezone. No such config was specified. In fact,UTC is not there anywhere in the repository at all.

Problem: I am aware that JDBC driver decides the timezone. 
Q) Should n't it always take JVM default timezone which in this case is Australia? 
Q) No matter what timezone I set in the code(either as default timezone or in the date column), it is always UTC in the DB. The numeric part of the timestamp is going correctly though. By any chance, is the JDBC taking DBtimezone instead of JVM's default timezone?
Q) Which timezone does JDBC take - JVM 's default or 'DBtimezone' of the DB(in this case,it happens to be the latter)? Or it can be any?

Info:
Dbtimezone of DB - select dbtimezone from dual - UTC
Sessiontimezone of DB - Asia/Calcutta
Created_date column is of type 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE'

Note: I tried with java.time classes.. OffsetdateTime and ZonedDateTime but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Never set the default time zone. Doing so immediately affects all other code running in all threads of all apps running within that JVM. And any other code can reset it again.

So never write code that relies on the JVM’s current default default time zone. Specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly.

> I am trying to insert a time stamp with Australia timezone in created_date column.

(A) Be certain your database column is of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

(B) Use only modern *java.time* types.

(C) Use a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 and above.

I do not use JPA. But I can show you straight JDBC,

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Perth" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

You may be getting confused by tools and middleware having an unfortunate anti-feature of dynamically applying a default time zone after retrieving the value from the database but before displaying to you. This creates the illusion of a time zone that is not really there. Try retrieving your value from DB using Java:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

You’ll have no time zone issues with the code shown on this Answer. In my experience with [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) and [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), there is no interplay with any default time zones on server or client. Stick to (a) using java.time classes, and (b) always specify your desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on a default zone. I do not use Spring or Hibernate, so I do not know if they might be injecting a time zone along the way.

Try some straight JDBC to eliminate Spring and JPA/Hibernate from the mix, while debugging your situation.

---

By the way, the time zone `Asia/Calcutta` has been renamed `Asia/Kolkata`. Make sure the [*tz data*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) within your operating systems, database engines, and Java implementations are all up-to-date.

Comment: I tried both....A) certain.checked it multiple times. B) Tried with that too. now, a different issue is observed. Tried setting America/Vancouver time now. Before inserting record, time is 2020-05-24T00:29:27.204. After inserting, it is 24-MAY-20 03.29.27.204000000 PM UTC.
Now, even numeric part is different. Earlier, at least that was getting inserted correctly.
Is it possible that JDBC is always taking dbtimezone?

Comment: You can set the jdbc timezone to hibernate in spring:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC

Comment: @zlaval - when I change the type of the column in database from TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE to String, it is working well. it is getting inserted with the timezone I am sending.
 Does JDBC consider DB server timezone too(in this case UTC) or it relies only on JVM default time zone? This is the question nobody has answered.

Comment: @PraveenNvs Sending a `OffsetDateTime` to a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` does not involve any time zone adjustments, but investigate the behavior of your particular JDBC driver. Also, you may be getting confused by tools and middleware having an unfortunate  anti-feature of dynamically applying a default time zone after retrieving the value from the database but before displaying to you. This creates the illusion of a time zone that is not really there. Try retrieving your value from DB using Java: `OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;`

Comment: @PraveenNvs Try some straight JDBC to eliminate Spring and Hibernate from the mix.

Comment: Will try.. Even if it does not take the timezone given by me, JDBC should take the JVM default timezone and not the DB server timezone .. right? In my case, DBServer timezone is UTC and JVM's is different. It seems to have taken DB's since UTC is inserted in DB. Can JDBC take as per its wish?

Comment: @PraveenNvs Using the code I have given you, in my experience with JDBC drivers for Postgres and H2, there is no interplay with any default time zones on server or client. Stick to using *java.time* classes, and always specify your desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on a default zone. I do not use Spring or Hibernate, so I do not know if they might be injecting a time zone along the way. Again, I suggest you run some straight JDBC without Spring/JPA/Hibernate adding to the confusion, until you get a handle on the situation.